# Are Question going to be worth 10 rep?

Tags: discussion

I just got an email from StackOverFlow [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?utm_source=iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=recalculating-reputation&utm_content=read-more)

Will this be implemented on this site?
Sorry I don't have more to add, just want to know what will happen here.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've read in the blog post you link to, this very much applies to the entirety of SE and as you can see in [your very own reputation history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/35258/kyloren?tab=reputation), this has already been applied retroactively to your existing questions.

Comment: I didn't realize that it would apply to my existing account. And finally to have something that I have always hoped to have happen is great.